# Cypress gpu_init.cc(441) passthrough is not supported GL is Swiftshader

Tags: webgl, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to setup Cypress in my project to run e2e tests and when I start it up I get the error
`Cypress gpu_init.cc(441) passthrough is not supported GL is Swiftshader`.

I've seen some people on here with the same error but with 'disabled' at the end instead of Swiftshader.

I think it has something to do with browser GPU acceleration but I don't know how to fix it.

I'm on MacOS and my project runs in a Ubuntu remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use Cypress on a remote machine but as it turns out remotes don't have the Cypress GUI because of $DISPLAY. Only working locally for me now.